# Virtual host not working for laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel, virtualhost

Troubling with virtual host Laravel route is not working well it can access the public/index.php but routing does not effective can any one please help me out in this concern.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName laravel.dev
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mylaravel/public/
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/mylaravel/public/>
        Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

After this setup, instead of getting result for a particular route it showing 404 error normal php style.

Answer (score 0):

You should point your web server (Apache) to a public directory, but you do not need to use `public` and `index.php` in your URLs and routes.

Correct routes are:

```
Route::get('foo/bar', function () {
    return 'Hello World';
});

Route::get('/', function () {
    return 'It's the index page!';
});
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#basic-routing

Answer (score 0):

For disable apache mod_rewite you are getting this problem.By this way,i solved my problem

```
//keep this in /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf file
<Directory /var/www/>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
allow from all
</Directory>

//enable mod rewrite
a2enmod rewrite

//restart apache
service apache2 restart
```

For more http://www.kingpabel.com/apache-mod-rewrite/